# Remove JSON Block with PHP

Tags: php, json

I have two JSON Files which I merge with a PHP Script. My PHP script looks like this:

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: application/json');

$a = file_get_contents("https://example.com/a.json", false);
$b = file_get_contents("https://example.com/b.json", false);

$merge = json_encode(array_merge(
  json_decode($a, true),
  json_decode($b, true)
));

echo $merge;

?>
```

My Output looks like this:

```
[{
    "id": 1141,
    "iid": 167,
    "project_id": 17,
    "title": "test",
    "description": "test",
    "state": "opened",
    "created_at": "2018-02-19T13:46:38.751Z",
    "updated_at": "2018-02-19T14:32:46.061Z",
    "closed_at": null,
    "labels": [],
    "milestone": null,
    "assignees": [],
    "author": {
        "id": 19,
        "state": "active"
    },
    "assignee": null,
    "user_notes_count": 0,
    "upvotes": 0,
    "downvotes": 0,
    "due_date": null,
    "confidential": false,
    "discussion_locked": null,
    "time_stats": {
        "time_estimate": 0,
        "total_time_spent": 0,
        "human_time_estimate": null,
        "human_total_time_spent": null
    }
}, {
    "id": 1140,
    "iid": 166,
    "project_id": 16,
    "title": "test2",
    "description": "test2",
    "state": "opened",
    "created_at": "2018-02-19T11:01:00.729Z",
    "updated_at": "2018-02-19T11:01:00.729Z",
    "closed_at": null,
    "labels": [],
    "milestone": null,
    "assignees": [{
        "id": 5,
        "state": "active"
    }],
    "author": {
        "id": 5,
        "state": "active"
    },
    "assignee": {
        "id": 5,
        "state": "active"
    },
    "user_notes_count": 0,
    "upvotes": 0,
    "downvotes": 0,
    "due_date": null,
    "confidential": false,
    "discussion_locked": null,
    "time_stats": {
        "time_estimate": 0,
        "total_time_spent": 0,
        "human_time_estimate": null,
        "human_total_time_spent": null
    }
}, {
    "id": 1136,
    "iid": 165,
    "project_id": 17,
    "title": "test3",
    "description": "test3",
    "state": "opened",
    "created_at": "2018-02-16T15:36:22.712Z",
    "updated_at": "2018-02-16T15:36:22.712Z",
    "closed_at": null,
    "labels": [],
    "milestone": null,
    "assignees": [{
        "id": 5,
        "state": "active"
    }],
    "author": {
        "id": 1,
        "state": "active"
    },
    "assignee": {
        "id": 5,
        "state": "active"
    },
    "user_notes_count": 0,
    "upvotes": 0,
    "downvotes": 0,
    "due_date": null,
    "confidential": false,
    "discussion_locked": null,
    "time_stats": {
        "time_estimate": 0,
        "total_time_spent": 0,
        "human_time_estimate": null,
        "human_total_time_spent": null
    }
}]
```

Now I want to remove each block with `"project_id": 16`. How can i remove every Block with `"project_id": 16`?

So i would like to remove this Block. And everyone else with `"project_id": 16`, if there were any more.

```
 {
    "id": 1140,
    "iid": 166,
    "project_id": 16,
    "title": "test2",
    "description": "test2",
    "state": "opened",
    "created_at": "2018-02-19T11:01:00.729Z",
    "updated_at": "2018-02-19T11:01:00.729Z",
    "closed_at": null,
    "labels": [],
    "milestone": null,
    "assignees": [{
        "id": 5,
        "state": "active"
    }],
    "author": {
        "id": 5,
        "state": "active"
    },
    "assignee": {
        "id": 5,
        "state": "active"
    },
    "user_notes_count": 0,
    "upvotes": 0,
    "downvotes": 0,
    "due_date": null,
    "confidential": false,
    "discussion_locked": null,
    "time_stats": {
        "time_estimate": 0,
        "total_time_spent": 0,
        "human_time_estimate": null,
        "human_total_time_spent": null
    }
},
```

I'm grateful for any help.

Comment: http://php.net/array-filter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here a little snippet

```
$merge = array_filter($merge, function($item){ return $item['project_id'] != 16 })
```